# open_bir restriction in effect at Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have put my wordpress on another server. I get the following error:

```
Warning: file_exists() [function.file-exists]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/ads4web/domains/ads4web.nl/public_html/spakmanbouw/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/06) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/hansgort/:/tmp:/var/tmp:/usr/local/lib/php/:/nfs/home/hansgort/:/home/hansgort/) in /home/hansgort/domains/spakman-bouw.nl/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1335

Warning: is_dir() [function.is-dir]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/ads4web/domains/ads4web.nl/public_html/spakmanbouw/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/hansgort/:/tmp:/var/tmp:/usr/local/lib/php/:/nfs/home/hansgort/:/home/hansgort/) in /home/hansgort/domains/spakman-bouw.nl/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1344

Warning: file_exists() [function.file-exists]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/ads4web/domains/ads4web.nl/public_html/spakmanbouw/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/hansgort/:/tmp:/var/tmp:/usr/local/lib/php/:/nfs/home/hansgort/:/home/hansgort/) in /home/hansgort/domains/spakman-bouw.nl/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1335

Warning: is_dir() [function.is-dir]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/ads4web/domains/ads4web.nl/public_html/spakmanbouw/blog/wp-content/uploads) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/hansgort/:/tmp:/var/tmp:/usr/local/lib/php/:/nfs/home/hansgort/:/home/hansgort/) in /home/hansgort/domains/spakman-bouw.nl/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1344

Warning: file_exists() [function.file-exists]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/ads4web/domains/ads4web.nl/public_html/spakmanbouw/blog/wp-content/uploads) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/hansgort/:/tmp:/var/tmp:/usr/local/lib/php/:/nfs/home/hansgort/:/home/hansgort/) in /home/hansgort/domains/spakman-bouw.nl/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1335

Warning: is_dir() [function.is-dir]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/ads4web/domains/ads4web.nl/public_html/spakmanbouw/blog/wp-content) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/hansgort/:/tmp:/var/tmp:/usr/local/lib/php/:/nfs/home/hansgort/:/home/hansgort/) in /home/hansgort/domains/spakman-bouw.nl/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1344

Warning: file_exists() [function.file-exists]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/ads4web/domains/ads4web.nl/public_html/spakmanbouw/blog/wp-content) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/hansgort/:/tmp:/var/tmp:/usr/local/lib/php/:/nfs/home/hansgort/:/home/hansgort/) in /home/hansgort/domains/spakman-bouw.nl/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1335

Warning: is_dir() [function.is-dir]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/ads4web/domains/ads4web.nl/public_html/spakmanbouw/blog) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/hansgort/:/tmp:/var/tmp:/usr/local/lib/php/:/nfs/home/hansgort/:/home/hansgort/) in /home/hansgort/domains/spakman-bouw.nl/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1344

Warning: file_exists() [function.file-exists]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/ads4web/domains/ads4web.nl/public_html/spakmanbouw/blog) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/hansgort/:/tmp:/var/tmp:/usr/local/lib/php/:/nfs/home/hansgort/:/home/hansgort/) in /home/hansgort/domains/spakman-bouw.nl/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1335

Warning: is_dir() [function.is-dir]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/ads4web/domains/ads4web.nl/public_html/spakmanbouw) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/hansgort/:/tmp:/var/tmp:/usr/local/lib/php/:/nfs/home/hansgort/:/home/hansgort/) in /home/hansgort/domains/spakman-bouw.nl/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1344

Warning: file_exists() [function.file-exists]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/ads4web/domains/ads4web.nl/public_html/spakmanbouw) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/hansgort/:/tmp:/var/tmp:/usr/local/lib/php/:/nfs/home/hansgort/:/home/hansgort/) in /home/hansgort/domains/spakman-bouw.nl/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1335

Warning: is_dir() [function.is-dir]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/ads4web/domains/ads4web.nl/public_html) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/hansgort/:/tmp:/var/tmp:/usr/local/lib/php/:/nfs/home/hansgort/:/home/hansgort/) in /home/hansgort/domains/spakman-bouw.nl/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1344

Warning: file_exists() [function.file-exists]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/ads4web/domains/ads4web.nl/public_html) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/hansgort/:/tmp:/var/tmp:/usr/local/lib/php/:/nfs/home/hansgort/:/home/hansgort/) in /home/hansgort/domains/spakman-bouw.nl/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1335

Warning: is_dir() [function.is-dir]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/ads4web/domains/ads4web.nl) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/hansgort/:/tmp:/var/tmp:/usr/local/lib/php/:/nfs/home/hansgort/:/home/hansgort/) in /home/hansgort/domains/spakman-bouw.nl/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1344

Warning: file_exists() [function.file-exists]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/ads4web/domains/ads4web.nl) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/hansgort/:/tmp:/var/tmp:/usr/local/lib/php/:/nfs/home/hansgort/:/home/hansgort/) in /home/hansgort/domains/spakman-bouw.nl/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1335

Warning: is_dir() [function.is-dir]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/ads4web/domains) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/hansgort/:/tmp:/var/tmp:/usr/local/lib/php/:/nfs/home/hansgort/:/home/hansgort/) in /home/hansgort/domains/spakman-bouw.nl/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1344

Warning: file_exists() [function.file-exists]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/ads4web/domains) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/hansgort/:/tmp:/var/tmp:/usr/local/lib/php/:/nfs/home/hansgort/:/home/hansgort/) in /home/hansgort/domains/spakman-bouw.nl/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1335

Warning: is_dir() [function.is-dir]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/ads4web) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/hansgort/:/tmp:/var/tmp:/usr/local/lib/php/:/nfs/home/hansgort/:/home/hansgort/) in /home/hansgort/domains/spakman-bouw.nl/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1344

Warning: file_exists() [function.file-exists]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/ads4web) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/hansgort/:/tmp:/var/tmp:/usr/local/lib/php/:/nfs/home/hansgort/:/home/hansgort/) in /home/hansgort/domains/spakman-bouw.nl/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1335

Warning: is_dir() [function.is-dir]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/hansgort/:/tmp:/var/tmp:/usr/local/lib/php/:/nfs/home/hansgort/:/home/hansgort/) in /home/hansgort/domains/spakman-bouw.nl/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1344

Warning: file_exists() [function.file-exists]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/hansgort/:/tmp:/var/tmp:/usr/local/lib/php/:/nfs/home/hansgort/:/home/hansgort/) in /home/hansgort/domains/spakman-bouw.nl/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1335

Warning: is_dir() [function.is-dir]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/hansgort/:/tmp:/var/tmp:/usr/local/lib/php/:/nfs/home/hansgort/:/home/hansgort/) in /home/hansgort/domains/spakman-bouw.nl/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1344

Warning: file_exists() [function.file-exists]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/hansgort/:/tmp:/var/tmp:/usr/local/lib/php/:/nfs/home/hansgort/:/home/hansgort/) in /home/hansgort/domains/spakman-bouw.nl/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1335

Warning: is_dir() [function.is-dir]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/hansgort/:/tmp:/var/tmp:/usr/local/lib/php/:/nfs/home/hansgort/:/home/hansgort/) in /home/hansgort/domains/spakman-bouw.nl/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1344

Warning: file_exists() [function.file-exists]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/ads4web/domains/ads4web.nl/public_html/spakmanbouw/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/06) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/hansgort/:/tmp:/var/tmp:/usr/local/lib/php/:/nfs/home/hansgort/:/home/hansgort/) in /home/hansgort/domains/spakman-bouw.nl/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1335

Warning: is_dir() [function.is-dir]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/ads4web/domains/ads4web.nl/public_html/spakmanbouw/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/hansgort/:/tmp:/var/tmp:/usr/local/lib/php/:/nfs/home/hansgort/:/home/hansgort/) in /home/hansgort/domains/spakman-bouw.nl/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1344

Warning: file_exists() [function.file-exists]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/ads4web/domains/ads4web.nl/public_html/spakmanbouw/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/hansgort/:/tmp:/var/tmp:/usr/local/lib/php/:/nfs/home/hansgort/:/home/hansgort/) in /home/hansgort/domains/spakman-bouw.nl/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1335

Warning: is_dir() [function.is-dir]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/ads4web/domains/ads4web.nl/public_html/spakmanbouw/blog/wp-content/uploads) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/hansgort/:/tmp:/var/tmp:/usr/local/lib/php/:/nfs/home/hansgort/:/home/hansgort/) in /home/hansgort/domains/spakman-bouw.nl/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1344

Warning: file_exists() [function.file-exists]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/ads4web/domains/ads4web.nl/public_html/spakmanbouw/blog/wp-content/uploads) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/hansgort/:/tmp:/var/tmp:/usr/local/lib/php/:/nfs/home/hansgort/:/home/hansgort/) in /home/hansgort/domains/spakman-bouw.nl/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1335

Warning: is_dir() [function.is-dir]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/ads4web/domains/ads4web.nl/public_html/spakmanbouw/blog/wp-content) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/hansgort/:/tmp:/var/tmp:/usr/local/lib/php/:/nfs/home/hansgort/:/home/hansgort/) in /home/hansgort/domains/spakman-bouw.nl/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1344

Warning: file_exists() [function.file-exists]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/ads4web/domains/ads4web.nl/public_html/spakmanbouw/blog/wp-content) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/hansgort/:/tmp:/var/tmp:/usr/local/lib/php/:/nfs/home/hansgort/:/home/hansgort/) in /home/hansgort/domains/spakman-bouw.nl/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1335

Warning: is_dir() [function.is-dir]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/ads4web/domains/ads4web.nl/public_html/spakmanbouw/blog) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/hansgort/:/tmp:/var/tmp:/usr/local/lib/php/:/nfs/home/hansgort/:/home/hansgort/) in /home/hansgort/domains/spakman-bouw.nl/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1344

Warning: file_exists() [function.file-exists]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/ads4web/domains/ads4web.nl/public_html/spakmanbouw/blog) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/hansgort/:/tmp:/var/tmp:/usr/local/lib/php/:/nfs/home/hansgort/:/home/hansgort/) in /home/hansgort/domains/spakman-bouw.nl/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1335

Warning: is_dir() [function.is-dir]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/ads4web/domains/ads4web.nl/public_html/spakmanbouw) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/hansgort/:/tmp:/var/tmp:/usr/local/lib/php/:/nfs/home/hansgort/:/home/hansgort/) in /home/hansgort/domains/spakman-bouw.nl/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1344

Warning: file_exists() [function.file-exists]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/ads4web/domains/ads4web.nl/public_html/spakmanbouw) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/hansgort/:/tmp:/var/tmp:/usr/local/lib/php/:/nfs/home/hansgort/:/home/hansgort/) in /home/hansgort/domains/spakman-bouw.nl/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1335

Warning: is_dir() [function.is-dir]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/ads4web/domains/ads4web.nl/public_html) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/hansgort/:/tmp:/var/tmp:/usr/local/lib/php/:/nfs/home/hansgort/:/home/hansgort/) in /home/hansgort/domains/spakman-bouw.nl/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1344

Warning: file_exists() [function.file-exists]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/ads4web/domains/ads4web.nl/public_html) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/hansgort/:/tmp:/var/tmp:/usr/local/lib/php/:/nfs/home/hansgort/:/home/hansgort/) in /home/hansgort/domains/spakman-bouw.nl/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1335

Warning: is_dir() [function.is-dir]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/ads4web/domains/ads4web.nl) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/hansgort/:/tmp:/var/tmp:/usr/local/lib/php/:/nfs/home/hansgort/:/home/hansgort/) in /home/hansgort/domains/spakman-bouw.nl/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1344

Warning: file_exists() [function.file-exists]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/ads4web/domains/ads4web.nl) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/hansgort/:/tmp:/var/tmp:/usr/local/lib/php/:/nfs/home/hansgort/:/home/hansgort/) in /home/hansgort/domains/spakman-bouw.nl/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1335

Warning: is_dir() [function.is-dir]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/ads4web/domains) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/hansgort/:/tmp:/var/tmp:/usr/local/lib/php/:/nfs/home/hansgort/:/home/hansgort/) in /home/hansgort/domains/spakman-bouw.nl/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1344

Warning: file_exists() [function.file-exists]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/ads4web/domains) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/hansgort/:/tmp:/var/tmp:/usr/local/lib/php/:/nfs/home/hansgort/:/home/hansgort/) in /home/hansgort/domains/spakman-bouw.nl/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1335

Warning: is_dir() [function.is-dir]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/ads4web) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/hansgort/:/tmp:/var/tmp:/usr/local/lib/php/:/nfs/home/hansgort/:/home/hansgort/) in /home/hansgort/domains/spakman-bouw.nl/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1344

Warning: file_exists() [function.file-exists]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/ads4web) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/hansgort/:/tmp:/var/tmp:/usr/local/lib/php/:/nfs/home/hansgort/:/home/hansgort/) in /home/hansgort/domains/spakman-bouw.nl/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1335

Warning: is_dir() [function.is-dir]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/hansgort/:/tmp:/var/tmp:/usr/local/lib/php/:/nfs/home/hansgort/:/home/hansgort/) in /home/hansgort/domains/spakman-bouw.nl/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1344

Warning: file_exists() [function.file-exists]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/hansgort/:/tmp:/var/tmp:/usr/local/lib/php/:/nfs/home/hansgort/:/home/hansgort/) in /home/hansgort/domains/spakman-bouw.nl/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1335

Warning: is_dir() [function.is-dir]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/hansgort/:/tmp:/var/tmp:/usr/local/lib/php/:/nfs/home/hansgort/:/home/hansgort/) in /home/hansgort/domains/spakman-bouw.nl/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1344

Warning: file_exists() [function.file-exists]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/hansgort/:/tmp:/var/tmp:/usr/local/lib/php/:/nfs/home/hansgort/:/home/hansgort/) in /home/hansgort/domains/spakman-bouw.nl/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1335

Warning: is_dir() [function.is-dir]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/hansgort/:/tmp:/var/tmp:/usr/local/lib/php/:/nfs/home/hansgort/:/home/hansgort/) in /home/hansgort/domains/spakman-bouw.nl/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1344

Warning: file_exists() [function.file-exists]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/ads4web/domains/ads4web.nl/public_html/spakmanbouw/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/06) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/hansgort/:/tmp:/var/tmp:/usr/local/lib/php/:/nfs/home/hansgort/:/home/hansgort/) in /home/hansgort/domains/spakman-bouw.nl/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1335

Warning: is_dir() [function.is-dir]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/ads4web/domains/ads4web.nl/public_html/spakmanbouw/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/hansgort/:/tmp:/var/tmp:/usr/local/lib/php/:/nfs/home/hansgort/:/home/hansgort/) in /home/hansgort/domains/spakman-bouw.nl/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1344

Warning: file_exists() [function.file-exists]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/ads4web/domains/ads4web.nl/public_html/spakmanbouw/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/hansgort/:/tmp:/var/tmp:/usr/local/lib/php/:/nfs/home/hansgort/:/home/hansgort/) in /home/hansgort/domains/spakman-bouw.nl/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1335

Warning: is_dir() [function.is-dir]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/ads4web/domains/ads4web.nl/public_html/spakmanbouw/blog/wp-content/uploads) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/hansgort/:/tmp:/var/tmp:/usr/local/lib/php/:/nfs/home/hansgort/:/home/hansgort/) in /home/hansgort/domains/spakman-bouw.nl/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1344

Warning: file_exists() [function.file-exists]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/ads4web/domains/ads4web.nl/public_html/spakmanbouw/blog/wp-content/uploads) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/hansgort/:/tmp:/var/tmp:/usr/local/lib/php/:/nfs/home/hansgort/:/home/hansgort/) in /home/hansgort/domains/spakman-bouw.nl/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1335

Warning: is_dir() [function.is-dir]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/ads4web/domains/ads4web.nl/public_html/spakmanbouw/blog/wp-content) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/hansgort/:/tmp:/var/tmp:/usr/local/lib/php/:/nfs/home/hansgort/:/home/hansgort/) in /home/hansgort/domains/spakman-bouw.nl/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1344

Warning: file_exists() [function.file-exists]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/ads4web/domains/ads4web.nl/public_html/spakmanbouw/blog/wp-content) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/hansgort/:/tmp:/var/tmp:/usr/local/lib/php/:/nfs/home/hansgort/:/home/hansgort/) in /home/hansgort/domains/spakman-bouw.nl/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1335

Warning: is_dir() [function.is-dir]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/ads4web/domains/ads4web.nl/public_html/spakmanbouw/blog) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/hansgort/:/tmp:/var/tmp:/usr/local/lib/php/:/nfs/home/hansgort/:/home/hansgort/) in /home/hansgort/domains/spakman-bouw.nl/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1344

Warning: file_exists() [function.file-exists]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/ads4web/domains/ads4web.nl/public_html/spakmanbouw/blog) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/hansgort/:/tmp:/var/tmp:/usr/local/lib/php/:/nfs/home/hansgort/:/home/hansgort/) in /home/hansgort/domains/spakman-bouw.nl/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1335

Warning: is_dir() [function.is-dir]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/ads4web/domains/ads4web.nl/public_html/spakmanbouw) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/hansgort/:/tmp:/var/tmp:/usr/local/lib/php/:/nfs/home/hansgort/:/home/hansgort/) in /home/hansgort/domains/spakman-bouw.nl/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1344

Warning: file_exists() [function.file-exists]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/ads4web/domains/ads4web.nl/public_html/spakmanbouw) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/hansgort/:/tmp:/var/tmp:/usr/local/lib/php/:/nfs/home/hansgort/:/home/hansgort/) in /home/hansgort/domains/spakman-bouw.nl/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1335

Warning: is_dir() [function.is-dir]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/ads4web/domains/ads4web.nl/public_html) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/hansgort/:/tmp:/var/tmp:/usr/local/lib/php/:/nfs/home/hansgort/:/home/hansgort/) in /home/hansgort/domains/spakman-bouw.nl/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1344

Warning: file_exists() [function.file-exists]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/ads4web/domains/ads4web.nl/public_html) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/hansgort/:/tmp:/var/tmp:/usr/local/lib/php/:/nfs/home/hansgort/:/home/hansgort/) in /home/hansgort/domains/spakman-bouw.nl/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1335

Warning: is_dir() [function.is-dir]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/ads4web/domains/ads4web.nl) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/hansgort/:/tmp:/var/tmp:/usr/local/lib/php/:/nfs/home/hansgort/:/home/hansgort/) in /home/hansgort/domains/spakman-bouw.nl/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1344

Warning: file_exists() [function.file-exists]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/ads4web/domains/ads4web.nl) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/hansgort/:/tmp:/var/tmp:/usr/local/lib/php/:/nfs/home/hansgort/:/home/hansgort/) in /home/hansgort/domains/spakman-bouw.nl/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1335

Warning: is_dir() [function.is-dir]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/ads4web/domains) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/hansgort/:/tmp:/var/tmp:/usr/local/lib/php/:/nfs/home/hansgort/:/home/hansgort/) in /home/hansgort/domains/spakman-bouw.nl/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1344

Warning: file_exists() [function.file-exists]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/ads4web/domains) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/hansgort/:/tmp:/var/tmp:/usr/local/lib/php/:/nfs/home/hansgort/:/home/hansgort/) in /home/hansgort/domains/spakman-bouw.nl/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1335

Warning: is_dir() [function.is-dir]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/ads4web) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/hansgort/:/tmp:/var/tmp:/usr/local/lib/php/:/nfs/home/hansgort/:/home/hansgort/) in /home/hansgort/domains/spakman-bouw.nl/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1344

Warning: file_exists() [function.file-exists]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/ads4web) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/hansgort/:/tmp:/var/tmp:/usr/local/lib/php/:/nfs/home/hansgort/:/home/hansgort/) in /home/hansgort/domains/spakman-bouw.nl/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1335

Warning: is_dir() [function.is-dir]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/hansgort/:/tmp:/var/tmp:/usr/local/lib/php/:/nfs/home/hansgort/:/home/hansgort/) in /home/hansgort/domains/spakman-bouw.nl/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1344

Warning: file_exists() [function.file-exists]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/hansgort/:/tmp:/var/tmp:/usr/local/lib/php/:/nfs/home/hansgort/:/home/hansgort/) in /home/hansgort/domains/spakman-bouw.nl/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1335

Warning: is_dir() [function.is-dir]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/hansgort/:/tmp:/var/tmp:/usr/local/lib/php/:/nfs/home/hansgort/:/home/hansgort/) in /home/hansgort/domains/spakman-bouw.nl/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1344

Warning: file_exists() [function.file-exists]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/hansgort/:/tmp:/var/tmp:/usr/local/lib/php/:/nfs/home/hansgort/:/home/hansgort/) in /home/hansgort/domains/spakman-bouw.nl/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1335

Warning: is_dir() [function.is-dir]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/hansgort/:/tmp:/var/tmp:/usr/local/lib/php/:/nfs/home/hansgort/:/home/hansgort/) in /home/hansgort/domains/spakman-bouw.nl/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1344

Warning: is_dir() [function.is-dir]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/ads4web/domains/ads4web.nl/public_html/spakmanbouw/blog/wp-content/uploads/wpcf7_uploads/) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/hansgort/:/tmp:/var/tmp:/usr/local/lib/php/:/nfs/home/hansgort/:/home/hansgort/) in /home/hansgort/domains/spakman-bouw.nl/public_html/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/modules/file.php on line 320

Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at /home/hansgort/domains/spakman-bouw.nl/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php:1335) in /home/hansgort/domains/spakman-bouw.nl/public_html/wp-content/themes/yoo_tasty_wp/warp/systems/wordpress/helpers/config.php on line 48

Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/hansgort/domains/spakman-bouw.nl/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php:1335) in /home/hansgort/domains/spakman-bouw.nl/public_html/wp-content/themes/yoo_tasty_wp/warp/systems/wordpress/helpers/config.php on line 48
```

I have searched on youtube but I haven't found the solutions.. please help me.. the site where you can see it is: spakman-bouw.nl

Comment: "I have searched on youtube but I haven't found the solutions..." It's usually better to search Google. :)

Comment: I mean Google ofcourse.